# Explanation for wrapping React HOC components with scalajs-react

Tags: reactjs, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am trying to understand @[trepidacious's](https://github.com/trepidacious) `scalajs-react` [wrapper](https://github.com/jhegedus42/scalajs-react-playaround/blob/5c3cac13067a1d61e4b3229f02777d9b003a1116/src/main/scala/wrappers/SortableElement.scala#L18) for [this](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc) HOC react component.

1a) Why is the type of the wrapped component [here](https://github.com/jhegedus42/scalajs-react-playaround/blob/5c3cac13067a1d61e4b3229f02777d9b003a1116/src/main/scala/wrappers/SortableElement.scala#L18) `ReactComponentC[P,_,_,_]` ?

1b) Why is the return type of the component `ReactComponentU_` ?

```
  def wrap[P](wrappedComponent: ReactComponentC[P,_,_,_]): Props => P => ReactComponentU_ = {
```

2) Why is the factory function passed to `SortableElement` [here](https://github.com/jhegedus42/scalajs-react-playaround/blob/5c3cac13067a1d61e4b3229f02777d9b003a1116/src/main/scala/wrappers/SortableElement.scala#L20) ?

```
val componentFactoryFunction = js.Dynamic.global.SortableElement(wrappedComponent.factory) ?
```

Does not `SortableElement` take a Component ?

3) Why are the wrapped props passed like [this](https://github.com/jhegedus42/scalajs-react-playaround/blob/5c3cac13067a1d61e4b3229f02777d9b003a1116/src/main/scala/wrappers/SortableElement.scala#L27) ?

```
  "v" -> wrappedProps.asInstanceOf[js.Any]
```

What is the reasoning behind this line  ?

Where is that magical `v` is coming from ? Is it from `scalajs-react` or from `react-sortable-hoc` ?

4) What is the reasoning behind this wrapper ? If I want to write a wrapper for another HOC component, what should be the general recepie for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a lot of parts here, but I've put together some links working from the lowest level to the highest while covering the questions.

The first and most important definitions are of React Components and React Elements. [This page](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) has an in-depth explanation - I recommend completely skipping the "Managing the Instances" section since it muddies the waters by describing a traditional UI model while using terms differently to the way they are used in React. In summary my understanding is that:

A React Component is a general concept that can be implemented in multiple ways. However it is implemented, it is essentially a function from props (and optionally state) to page contents - a renderer.

A React Element is a description of page contents, representing a particular rendering of a Component.

[React components and props docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) describe the two ways of defining a React component, the first one is a function from props to a react element, this is the one we're interested in. The [React.createFactory](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createfactory) docs then confirm that we can pass such a function to createFactory. As far as I can tell this exists in order to adapt from the multiple ways of defining a React Component (by subclassing React.Component or React.PureComponent, by using React.createClass, or by a function from Props to ReactElement) to a way of rendering props to a ReactElement. We can see something about this by looking at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/d7bce729f38730399d28) introducing React.createFactory in React 0.12 - essentially they wanted to introduce some abstraction between the class used to define a React Component and the eventual function from props to React Elements that is used when rendering, rather than just letting the class render props directly.

Next we have a minor wrinkle - `React.createFactory` is flagged as legacy in the docs. Luckily this isn't a major issue, again as far as I can tell `React.createFactory(type)` just produces a function `f(props)` that is identical to `React.createElement(type, props)` - we are just fixing the `type` argument in `React.createElement`. I've tested this in the react-sortable-hoc wrapper, and we can use createElement instead of createFactory:

```
val componentFunction = js.Dynamic.global.SortableContainer(wrappedComponent.factory)
(props) => (wrappedProps) => {
  val p = props.toJS
  p.updateDynamic("v")(wrappedProps.asInstanceOf[js.Any])
  React.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].createElement(componentFunction, p).asInstanceOf[ReactComponentU_]
}
```

We're now nearly at question 2). If we look at [the source for SortableElement](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/blob/master/src/SortableElement/index.js) we can see that the `sortableElement` function accepts a `WrappedComponent` argument - this is used to create another React Component, via the "subclass React.Component" approach. In the `render` function of this class, we can see that `WrappedComponent` is used as a React Component, so we know that it is indeed a component, even without a static type :) This means that WrappedComponent needs to be something accepted by `React.createElement`, since this is what a [JSX component use desugars to](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

Therefore we know that we need to pass to the `sortableElement` function something that is usable as a React Component in javascript `React.createElement` function. Looking at the [scalajs-react types doc](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/TYPES.md) we can see that ReactComponentC looks like a good bet - it constructs components, presumably from props. Looking [at the source for this](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/ReactComponentC.scala) we can see that we have two promising looking values - `reactClass` and `factory`. At this point I realise that the code is probably using the wrong one - I've tried replacing `.factory` with `.reactClass` and this still works, but makes much more sense since we have the comment to tell us that it gives `Output of [[React.createClass()]]`, which is one of the options for a valid React Component. I suspect that `factory` also works by essentially wrapping up the provided component in createFactory twice, since the output of createFactory is also usable as its input... I think given this correction we've answered question 2 :) This also pretty much answers question 1a) - `ReactComponentC` is the scala trait that gets us the `.reactClass` val we need for a scala-defined React Component. We only care about the type of props it uses (since we have to provide them), hence the `P`. Since scala IS typed we know that this is what we get from building a scala React Component in the normal way (at least for components I've tried).

On question 1b), I found the type `ReactComponentU_` from code like the `ReactCssTransitionGroup` facade in [scalajs-react Addons](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/Addons.scala) and the [scalajs-react-components notes on interop](https://github.com/chandu0101/scalajs-react-components/blob/master/doc/InteropWithThirdParty.md), which shows wrapping of a non-HOC component. Looking at the type itself we can see that it extends `ReactElement`, which makes sense - this is the expected result of rendering a React Component. In our `wrap` function in the `SortableElement` and `SortableContainer` facades we are producing (eventually) another function from props to ReactElement, just one that jumps through a few hoops to get there with the HOC approach. I'm not sure why `ReactComponentU_` is used instead of just `ReactElement`, I think this is to do with tracking the state of components through the type, but the code still compiles if I return `ReactElement`, which is odd.

Question 3) is much easier - scalajs-react works with Props that can be Ints, Longs etc. but in Javascript these are not objects. To make every scalajs component's props be an object, scalajs-react wraps them in an object like `{"v": props}`, and then unwraps again when they are used. When we wrap a Scala React Component using the HOC, we need to get that wrapped component's props to it somehow. The component produced by the HOC function (the "wrapping" component, SortableElement or SortableContainer) does this by expecting its own props to already contain the wrapped component's props as fields, and it then just lets these flow through to the wrapped component, for example in SortableElement's render:

```
<WrappedComponent
                ref={ref}
                {...omit(this.props, 'collection', 'disabled', 'index')}
            />
```

`this.props` is passed through to the wrapped component. Since the wrapped scala component requires a "v" field with the scala props object in it, we need to add this to the wrapper component's props. Luckily this field will then pass through unaltered to be interpreted later by the scala component. You won't see the "v" field since scalajs-react will unwrap it for you.

This does raise a problem when wrapping some other HOCs - for example [ReactGridLayout's WidthProvider](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/lib/components/WidthProvider.jsx) measures the wrapped component's width and passes it through in the props as `{"width": width}`, but unfortunately we can't see this from scala. There may well be some workaround for this.

That covers the details and references for the parts of the HOC wrapping, but actually the process is pretty easy (providing you don't want to access props "injected" into the wrapped component):

1. Make a scala object for the facade to organise the code.
2. Work out what props are required by the wrapper component. For example in `SortableElement` this is `index`, `collection` and `disabled`. Make a Props case class with these fields, in the facade object.
3. Write a 'wrap' function in the facade object. This does the following:
4. Accepts a `wrappedComponent: ReactComponentC[P,_,_,_]` and passes it to the javascript HOC function (e.g. `SortableElement`) to produce a new React Component.
5. Builds a javascript props object with the wrapper component's props AND the magic "v" field with the wrapped component's props.
6. Uses javascript React.createElement function to produce a ReactElement that renders the wrapped component, and casts this to ReactComponentU_.

Note that at stage 5 we need to convert from our Scala Props case class (the wrapper component's props) to a plain javascript object that can be understood by the HOC. The wrapped component's props just go straight into the "v" field without conversion, just casting to `js.Any`.

The code I wrote for SortableElement and SortableContainer splits this up a little so that wrap returns a curried function that accepts the props for the wrapper component and produces another function from the wrapped props to the final React element. This means that you can provide the wrapper props once and then use the resulting function like a normal component in your Scala render code.

I've updated the [SortableElement facade](https://github.com/trepidacious/tree-material-ui/blob/master/js/src/main/scala/org/rebeam/tree/view/sortable/SortableElement.scala) with the improvements above, and this is pretty much a minimal example of a HOC facade now. I would imagine other HOCs will look very similar. You could probably abstract some of the code for the purposes of DRY, but actually there's not really a lot there anyway.

Thanks for the questions and for helping work this out - looking back through the process and particularly your question on `.factory` has left me more confident that this is now working the right way (with the changes described).

Answer (score 3):

I don't have all the answers but my understanding is that the author of [`scalajs-react`](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react) uses lots of types to prevent errors during construction of components as well as during the lifecycle of the components once constructed. He uses naming conventions with suffixes and letters to separate the types which make sense but can be daunting at first.

1a) [`ReactComponentC`](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/635e94f6b3d695663fb42ed13b458bed413afe63/core/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/ReactComponentC.scala#L8) is a constructor for a component (`C` as in Constructor).

1b) [`ReactComponentU_`](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/635e94f6b3d695663fb42ed13b458bed413afe63/core/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/types.scala#L179) represents an unmounted native (JavaScript) React component.

3) I think, looking at the `scalajs-react` source, that yes, "v" is a magic key name. There is (was?) also some notes in the source code to the effect that this is not ideal ;)

There is a [plan to simplify](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/issues/259) `scalajs-react`'s types in a [new version](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/tree/topic/neo).